# Как обратится к классу кнопки в kivy&python

Tags: python, kivy

Есть класс кнопки в .kv, как к нему обратится, при спавне кнопок в python файле.

.kv

```
<Meny@Button>:
    text: self.text
    font_size: '40sp'
    color: 0,0,0,1
<Level>:
   GridLayout:
       cols: 3
       id: test
       spacing: '20dp'
```

.py

```
class Level(Screen):
    on_enter(self, *args):
        for x in range(0,10):
            self.spawn = ???
            self.ids.test.add_widget(self.spawn)
```

Нужно чтобы заспавнилось 10 кнопок, в по 3 на колону.
Но я не знаю что нужно вставить в "???".
Я пытался создавать класс class Meny(Button), и вызывать его. Но выводилась обычная кнопка без стиля и тд... К тому же создавалась совсем ненужная кнопка сбоку.
И вот я думаю, можно ли класс из kv вызвать в py файле

Comment: напишите более подробно

Comment: Написад более подробнее.

Comment: А разве не self.spawn = Menu(text='test')? Хотя очень желательно привести минимально воспроизводимый код описывающий вашу проблему. Без примера можно гадать сколько угодно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правило в KV файле (в твоем случае это правило `Meny`) не имеет базового класса Python, то используй фабрику (`from kivy.factory import Factory`):

```
self.spawn = Factory.Meny(text=text)
```